# Redirect domain.co.uk to www.domain.co.uk with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, web

I would like to redirect domain.co.uk to www.domain.co.uk

I use this rule to redirect domain.ca to www.domain.ca but it doesn't work for domain.co.uk :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.([a-z-]+\.[a-z]{2,6})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

If this is possible, I'm also looking to redirect anything.subdomain.domain.co.uk to subdomain.domain.co.uk

I tried many other things but nothing works, any idea ?